# Is there a way to stretch or alter text size? C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making a game in c++ using ASCII and I need to stretch/shrink the text because everything is stretched on the Y axis

Example:

[image]

I have tried SetConsoleTextAttribute, but if I set the x and y to try to adjust the text it only scales it aka X and Y together.

Current Code:

`HANDLE m_hConsole;`

```
void ASCIIRenderer::InitialisePixelSize(int fontx, int fonty)
{
    
    PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX font_size = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX();

    font_size->cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(m_hConsole, false, font_size);

    font_size->dwFontSize.X = fontx;    //Width of element in buffer
    font_size->dwFontSize.Y = fonty;    //Hieght of element in buffer

    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(m_hConsole, false, font_size);  //Set the new font size
}
```

Is there a way to alter the X or Y to effectively stretch/shrink the text?

Comment: I assume you want square "pixels." You could then take advantage of the fact that the characters have roughly 1:2 aspect ratio, i. e. 2 characters next to each other will make a square

Comment: the disadvantage of that is every time I want to make a new sprite(grid of text characters) I would have to double all of the text characters for the sprite which take a long time and could cause problems because it's all manually typed in. it would be simpler and less complicated in the long run to change the size of the text.

Comment: Find a font with a size, family, or such that has square glyphs. If no system fonts have that, you can load most font files with `AddFontResource()`. On a side note, don't use `new` to allocate the `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX`, just declare it locally and set the `cbSize`. To pass a pointer into functions, use `&font_size`

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you could try to use [DirectWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/introducing-directwrite) to stretch/shrink the text. For example, you could try to use [IDWriteFactory::CreateTextFormat method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritefactory-createtextformat)